# ¿Cual es la manera correcta de iniciar otra clase en Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Para cargar otra clase o llamar a otro layout yo uso esta sentencia:

```
StartActivity(typeof(ClaseB));
```

//Mi ClaseB:

```
base.OnCreate(bundle);
RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);   
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LayoutB);
```

Y funciona muy bien para cargar la clase e invocar otro layout; el problema es que cuando uso la flecha de volver que trae por defecto el celular me va regresando a todos los layouts que mande a cargar anteriormente.

Osea, si primero vi el layout A, luego el B y por último el C. 
Me va devolviendo del C al B, del B al A y así sucesivamente.
Es por eso que me imagino que la manera correcta debe ser algo como, llamar a la clase y luego destruir la clase anterior.

Como lo hacen ustedes?

Comment: al llamar StartActivity() usa Finish(); para que cierre la Activity y al regresar no este "viva".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma correcta para iniciar una Activity se realiza mediante el método [**StartActivity()**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.content.context.startactivity?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9#Android_Content_Context_StartActivity_System_Type_) :

```
StartActivity(typeof(Actividad));
```

por **si lo deseas realizar es que no se mantenga la `Activity` desde la cual se inicia la `Activity`, debes usar el método** **[Finish()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.activity.finish?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9)** :

```
    StartActivity(typeof(Actividad));
    Finish();
```

De esta forma al regresar, no se mostrará la Activity anterior.

Answer (score 0):

puedes sobre escribirl el siguiente metodo:

```
public override void OnBackPressed ()
{
  StartActivity(typeof(ClaseA));
}
```

este se ejecuta al presionar el botón de ir atras